# Не работает эмулятор для тестирования андроид приложения

Tags: android, юнит-тесты, эмулятор

появилась проблема, что не Android Studio не запускает эмулятор Tablet, однако запускается спокойно
другой эмулятор, но телефон. Пыталась добавлять памяти в эмулятор, но все равно не получается его запустить.
В чем может быть причина такого? Из-за его размера?

Comment: Есть какой-нибудь код ошибки?

Comment: @DanilApsadikov, студия пишет, что эмулятор был terminated и все

Comment: Посмотрите тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67346232/android-emulator-issues-in-new-versions-the-emulator-process-has-terminated Возможно это решит проблему

Comment: @DanilApsadikov Спасибо за ответ!